# Scala: Are Pattern Matching and Match Expression the Same in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I see many sources which are titled pattern matching in Scala, but they only discuss match expressions.  Is pattern matching in Scala used only in match expressions? Can someone provide a clear understanding of pattern matching versus match expression in Scala?

Should I consider pattern matching a much vaster concept than match expressions?  And consider match expression only one of the usages of pattern matching?  or in Scala the 2 concepts are thought of as synonyms?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by *match expression* which doesn't refer to pattern matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` expressions are just one way to use pattern matching.   The same concepts are used in a variety of context,such as:

```
//Exception handling    
try{
   //....
} catch {
   case ex: NullPointerException => ex.printStackTrace()
   case Exception(msg) => println(msg)
   case _ => println("error")
}
```

and

```
// Map/flatMap/filter for collections
val l  = List(1, "2", 3L, Some(1L))
l.foreach { 
 case l:Long => println("Long 1")
 case s:String => println(s)
 case Some(n) => println(n)
 case None => println("error")
 case _ => println("dunno")
}
```

Comment: Jon:  In both examples above you have case statements.  Does this mean that in Scala anytime pattern matching is involved, the keyword "case" is used?  Or that there are constructs using pattern matching that don't use the keyword "case"?

Comment: Yes.  For example, if you chain multiple PartialFunctions together using `orElse` that implement  `isDefinedAt`, you can accomplish the same effect.  Using `case` is simpler.

Comment: An actual example of pattern matching without `case` is `val (a, b) = (1, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks Alexey; that's exactly what I was looking for; this shows that pattern matching is used in Scala in places other than match expression without even the need of case clauses.